# Mac Pro crashed and wants to recover files on hard drive

Tags: software-recommendation, data-recovery, hdd

I have a Mac Pro and the motherboard is damaged and I'm trying to retrieve the files from the hard disk on my Windows 7 desktop. Can anyone tell me what software i can use?

Windows 7 cannot read HFS+

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of programs that do this, MacDrive and HFS-Windows spring to mind. Both are commercial software but not especially expensive.

there is a freeware solution but I have never used it: HFSExplorer:

http://www.catacombae.org/hfsx.html

Will allow you to read only from HFS drives.